# Passing Address details via the Buy Now button

Tags: paypal

I am trying to pass my users details to Paypal screen using the appropriate html variables but only some are getting passed!?!?!? This is driving me mad! The order details are fine.

My code is:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" />
@*Order Details*@
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="sales@xxxxxx.co.uk">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Order Number 123">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="200.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
@*Address Stuff *@
<input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="Barry">
<input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="White">
<input type="hidden" name="address1" value="1 Big Street">
<input type="hidden" name="address2" value="Big Mountain">
<input type="hidden" name="city" value="Big City">
<input type="hidden" name="country" value="GB">
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="Bob@bob.com">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="UK">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/GB/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" 
border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online." />
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
</form>
```

The paypal screen shows some of the fields (name, email country!) but not all

Why are some of the fields populating and some not!!!!!!!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if you don't supply all the address details then it will not display any!

If I add the zip field then it displays the address.

Paypal integration should be so simple but their documentation is so bad - shows what monopolies do for you.

all the address fields are optional according to the documentation ffs